# Python: Join three dataframe considering given conditions w.r.t. Space allocated

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, join

Have got 3 input dataframe like below:

*df_space*

```
Item        Space
Grape       0.125
Beans       0.0
Mango       0.25
Beetroot    0.375
Carrot      0.5
Banana      1.0
```

*df_item*

```
Category    Item
AA          Carrot
AA          Beetroot
BB          Beans
CC          Grape
CC          Mango
DD          Banana
EE          Cabbage
FF          Tomato
```

*df_ded*

```
Table_No    Part    Dedicated_Item  
1           1       null        
1           2       null        
1           3       null        
1           5       Potato      
1           6       null        
1           7       null        
1           8       null        
2           1       null        
2           2       Onion
2           3       null        
2           5       null                
2           6       null        
2           7       null        
2           8       null        
3           1       Avocado
3           2       null        
3           3       null        
3           4       null        
3           5       null        
3           6       null        
3           7       null        
3           8       Potato
```

***Scenario:***
*df_ded* is the base dataframe in which `Item` from *df_item* to be filled in the same order considering `space` for each Item from *df_space*.

1. (*df_ded*)Each `Table_No` holds 8 `Part`.
2. (*df_ded*)Rows with '`null`' values in `Dedicated` column alone need to considered.
3. (*df_space*)Each `Item` given `Space` (in terms of 1/8th). Need not consider Items with *space* `zero`.
   *Eg.:* 0.125 equivalent to 1 Part among 8 in Single Table.
   0.25 - 2 Part, 0.375 - 3 Part, 0.5 - 4 Part, 0.625 - 5 Part, 0.75 - 6 Part, 0.875 - 7 Part, 1.0 - 8 Part

***Expected Output:***

```
Table_No    Part    Dedicated   Item        Category
1           1       null        Carrot      AA
1           2       null        Carrot      AA
1           3       null        Carrot      AA
1           5       Potato      
1           6       null        Carrot      AA
1           7       null        Beetroot    AA
1           8       null        Beetroot    AA
2           1       null        Beetroot    AA
2           2       Onion
2           3       null        Grape       CC
2           5       null        Mango       CC              
2           6       null        Mango       CC
2           7       null        Banana      DD
2           8       null        Banana      DD
3           1       Avocado
3           2       null        Banana      DD
3           3       null        Banana      DD
3           4       null        Banana      DD
3           5       null        Banana      DD
3           6       null        Banana      DD
3           7       null        Banana      DD
3           8       Potato
```

Any help appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: Can you pose a more specific question? I don't seem to follow the logic condition, how your 3 input dfs are connected to the desired output. What's the rule how the 3 input sets should be combined?

Comment: 'Item' from df_item need to be included in df_ded in same order. While adding so each 'Item' need to be added considering 'space' from df_space (As mentioned in Qus).

Answer (score 1):

Your pandas approach is a bit weird: You want to build a `DataFrame` that has a structural layout that reflects information of another `DataFrame` (8 rows meaning that each item needs space 1/8). That will get you into trouble.. But let's try to fix it.

Let me rephrase your question - let me know if that is what you need: We want to fill the `null`-spaces in `df_ded` with a certain number of items from another list (which may or may not be of the same length). Then, let's do this:

1. First, create an exhaustive list of 'Items' that you need, which will become 'rows' in the final DataFrame: Take the `Space` information from `df_space['Space']` to determine an exact `item_list` that contains each Item `x` number of times (This has/should have nothing to to with pandas, it's a pure logic/numpy exercise. Spoiler alert: what do you do if your `1/space` information is not an integer? If space is `0.4` you won't be able to add `2.5` rows to a pandas DataFrame --> solve that logic problem first, outside of pandas) First you need to figure out what you actually want to put on your racks
2. Sort that `item_list` in the same order as `df_item['Item']`. That will give you a `sorted_item_list`, which has exactly the same length as you want to have total count of items in your shop. We can fill the output with that list, starting from the top (Spoiler alert: Is that really the filling logic? If you have too many items, do you really want to fill from the top, and have 100% of Carrots, but drop all the chocolate, because it comes at the end of the list?)
3. Save that `sorted_item_list` information into `df_ded`, filling from the top: Wherever you currently have a `null` value in `df_ded` (not a dedicated space), you can place one item from your list - where the order or placing them comes from your sorted list. You can do this via `df_ded.loc[df_ded['Dedicated_Item'].isnull(), 'Item'] = sorted_item_list`

This bridges the gap between "Space required by items" and "null-spaces in `df_ded`". But **attention:** This step 3 can only work if your sorted list has exactly the same length as the count of null-spaces in your `df_ded`. This would be a magic conincidence.. But that sounds pretty much like a real-world problem: Imagine you have a truck delivering 10 boxes. but you have only shelf space of 9, then you need to decide which items not to put on the rack. (It's totally unclear from your question whether the `Space` information for `Item` ties up with the `null` dedicated spaces you have available). Let's assume you have a perfect order, and the `null`-spaces can fit your products, then this will work..

4. Finally, do a left-merge of the `Category` information into that DataFrame `pd.merge(df_ded, df_item, how='left', on='Item')`